# Изменить строку адреса, но не изменять страницу

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли посредством JavaScript вместо названия документа, написать любое имя, но при этом не менять текущий документ.
Как если бы я сделал так: `window.location.pathname = 'vasya'`, но при этом, документ в окне, нужно оставить прежним.

Answer (score 1):

*Раз уж этот вопрос всплыл, дам на него ответ.*

До появления HTML5 и правда нельзя было менять ничего, кроме якоря. Но с появлением HistoryAPI все изменилось.

`window.history.pushState(data, title, url)` - вот ответ на оригинальный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

В кратце - можно менять только якорь(#lalala).

Почитайте http://javascript.ru/window-location всё подробно расписано.

Comment: Не новость конечно что можно изменять только якорь, но где то на хабре не видел что можно и pathname менять.
К тому же, вк же на ajax построен, тогда как он меняет адрес? Там ведь, при переходе на другую страницу, вся страница не перезагружается.

Comment: А вот и перегружается :)
Просто эффект "неперезагружаемости" дает то, что в Куки записывается текущее состояние страницы :) Чтобы потом воспроизвести то же, что и было до перезагрузки (например, окна чата) :)

Ну нельзя... просто физически нельзя изменить адрес ссылки без перезагрузки страницы.... если только менять якорь :)

Comment: Нет, не перезагружается :)
Почему тогда например плеер, без прерывно воспроизводит аудиозапись? Да это даже на глаз заметно.
А используется там window.history.pushState(), а в IE все тоже window.location.hash.

Comment: VK не перезагружается, он построен на технологии node.js.
А так не сработает?

    location.href = someurl;
    return false;

Comment: VK на node.js, ах-ах-ха-ха-ха! Хорошая шутка.